# How to Create Random and Tags Posts on File System Generated Posts NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lodash, blogs, chakra-ui

[image]
Hello guys, i might need help to create random and specific tags posts on my Case. I in working create products showcase using NextJS and Generating markdown files into static posts using File System Module (fs) on my project to generate post page.
[image]
[image]

Since the generated posts was created by markdown files and doesn't have indexes, how to create some random posts component or some tags filtered posts since it doesn't have indexes to use math?

Repository : https://github.com/dendense/indie-showcase
Demo : aero-navy.com

I've tried using lodash module to create randomize post
`

```
const _ = require("lodash");
            const randomizePost = data.map((post) => {
              const { title, path } = post;
              return (
                <PostList key={`${title}`} title={title} path={path}></PostList>
              );
            });
            let result = _.sampleSize(randomizePost, 4);
            return <ul className="list-group post-list">{result}</ul>;
```

`

But still no idea, please help